# Ограничение размера Dialog

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

У меня есть диалоговое окно,в котором содержится `RecyclerView`.При добавлении элементов окно становится выше.Как сделать так, чтобы окно "росло" до определенного момента?Знаю,что есть параметр `minHeight` , но в моем случае мне нужна наоборот,максимальная высота.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте сделать вот так:

Создайте класс

```
private static class OnViewGlobalLayoutListener implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
private final static int maxHeight = 130;
private View view;

public OnViewGlobalLayoutListener(View view) {
    this.view = view;
}

@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    if (view.getHeight() > maxHeight)
        view.getLayoutParams().height = maxHeight;
}
}
```

Затем добавьте слушатель к вашему view (в вашем случае recyclerview):

```
view.getViewTreeObserver()
              .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnViewGlobalLayoutListener(view));
```

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425758/how-to-set-a-maximum-height-with-wrap-content-in-android)

Comment: Большое спасибо,вы мне очень помогли)